# Getting "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'" error with PIL library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from PIL import Image, ExifTags

img = Image.open("/root/Bilder/sysPics/schwarz-weiß-Karte.jpg")

for i, j in img._getexif().items():
    if i in ExifTags.TAGS:
        print(ExifTags.TAGS[i] + " - " + str(j))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python-tool.py", line 7, in <module>
    for i, j in img._getexif().items():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Can anyone help me? I never worked with the PIL lib but I saw a tutorial,
in which this `.items()` method worked:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-PiR5SX4Mxo&list=PLNmsVeXQZj7onbtIXvxZTzeKGnzI6NFp_&index=8

There is no difference between his code and mine, I can't believe they cut off the `.items()` method in the last patches.

Answer (score 4):

1st, you should not be relying on internal functions such as `_get_exif()` because their implementation can change at any time and they are usually not meant for public use. (See [`_single_leading_underscore`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) from PEP8 naming conventions).

2nd, you should consider that not all images have EXIF data. It’s possible that trying to get the EXIF data will `None`. So it's not the `.items()` method that's the problem, rather it's that your `_get_exif()` returned `None`. Your code does not have handling for that case, you are always assuming `_get_exif()` returns a `dict`.

Now, to solve your problem, for Python3.x (I have Python3.6.8) and PIL (installed as Pillow, `Pillow==6.0.0`), the `Image` object now provides a public `getexif()` method that you can use. The return type is `None` if the image has no EXIF data or a `<class 'PIL.Image.Exif'>`.

```py
from PIL import Image, ExifTags

img = Image.open("sample.jpg")
print(dir(img))
# [... 'getexif' ...]

img_exif = img.getexif()
if img_exif:
    print(type(img_exif))
    # <class 'PIL.Image.Exif'>
    print(dict(img_exif))
    # { .. 271: 'FUJIFILM', 305: 'Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 6.14 (Macintosh)', }

    img_exif_dict = dict(img_exif)
    for key, val in img_exif_dict.items():
        if key in ExifTags.TAGS:
            print(ExifTags.TAGS[key] + " - " + str(val))
else:
    print("Sorry, image has no exif data.")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped me a lot! :)

Comment: @5thAveApe And I updated my answer to add your original code, where you loop through the `.items()` and print `ExifTags.TAGS[key] + " - " + str(val)`.

Comment: This was very useful, wondering if it can be found in the docs.  I searched a lot and this was the only reference I found stating there was a public method in pillow that could be used to replace the "experimental" underscore method, which is mentioned in the docs.

Comment: @Karr Yeah, I was also looking for docs on it when writing this answer, but I could not find it from the [Image Module API docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#functions). I found it instead from source ([Pillow/Image.py](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/6.0.x/src/PIL/Image.py#L1300)) then verified it with `dir`.